# Host developed wcf service on azure

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight, azure

I have ready project in silverlight, which is using wcf services. 
I have one project for silverlight app and another for wcf services.
Can I move this wcf services from project to azure simple?
Or I have to rebuild all project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 options.

1. Host your project as an IIS project on a Windows Server Virtual machine in Azure. No coding would be necessary, but you'd have to move your project to IIS.
2. Recode your Project as an Azure Cloud Service. It's not that difficult. I show an example of how to do that with an ASMX service in the below video, but moving a WCF service should be much easier than even this was.

Video is at:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQbMnoG56lk